# Fermat's Little Theorem and solving $n^2 \equiv -1 \pmod p$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

This problem is asked quite often; I want to check whether my approach is right.

Let  $ p = 4k+1 $ be prime.   Then there exists integer $n$ such that

$ n^2 \equiv -1$  (mod $p $) .

Approach : 
By Fermat's Little  Theorem ,

$  n^{4k}\equiv 1 $ (mod p )

$ => (n^{2k}-1)(n^{2k}+1) \equiv 0  $

$=>  (n^{2k}+1) \equiv 0 . $

As  $ n^{4k}-1\equiv 0 $ (mod p ).

=> $n^{2k}+1 \equiv 0 $

=>$  (n^k)^2  +1 \equiv 0 $ ( mod p) .

Is this right ?

Comment: Fermat's Little Theorem says that for all $n$ not divisible by $p, n^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod p$; you have to show that for some $n, n^2 \equiv 1 \pmod p$

Comment: For $k = 1$ (mod 2), it holds in last second step and i need to show  $n^2 \equiv -1 $ (mod p ) .

Comment: You have not shown that $p\nmid(n^{2k}-1)$ for some $n$. This is necessary for you to eliminate the factor.

Comment: I meant $n^2 \equiv -1 \pmod p.$   But for example $2^6+1\equiv 0 \pmod {13}$, but that doesn't mean $2^2+1\equiv 0\pmod {13}$

Comment: How can we do that ,i.e., $p\nmid(n^{2k}-1)$ . By FLT , $p\mid(n^{4k}-1)$ .

Comment: I fixed what appeared to be a typo in your final congruence. If that's not what you intended then please revert the edit and elaborate.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in comments, the implications in your attempted proof are not legitimate.

Try this.  Let $a$ be a primitive root modulo the prime $p.$  Then can you show, using Fermat’s Little Theorem, that $n=a^k,$ where $p=4k+1,$ is a solution to $n^2 \equiv -1 \pmod p?$

Comment: Can you elaborate ? It is un-understable till now .

Comment: What part don't you understand?  It is known that for prime $p$ there exists [primitive root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n) $a$, where $a^{p-1}$ is the smallest power of $a$ congruent to $1 \pmod p$

Comment: @Doraemon It's essentially the same as your attempted proof, except he chose your $\,n\,$ with order $= 4k,$ so $\,n^{2k}\not\equiv 1,\,$ which validates your cancellation.

Comment: Thanks I got it :)